# How to loop a dictionary with list inside it?

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve the desired output as shown, but what I get are:

```
('A', 'B')Z
Z('A', 'B')
('C', 'B')Z
Z('C', 'B')
```

```
symbols1 = ('A','B')
symbols2 = ('C','D')

symbolsC = {symbols1:('A','B'),symbols2:('C','D')}

for symbol in symbolsC:

    print(str(symbol)+'Z')
    print('Z'+str(symbol))
 
 #desired final outout: AZ, BZ , ZC and ZD
```

Comment: Your intention is a bit unclear. The keys and values are the same, so what is the purpose of the dictionary at all? Also, what makes it so that `Z` should be after `A` and `B`, but before `C` and `D`? This seems a little arbitrary.

Comment: take a look at `itertools.product`

Comment: Your question title could be much clearer. You're already looping the keys of a dictionary, but seems you're misunderstanding what `str()` on a tuple object does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i write it like this because i wasn't sure why you need that tuples:

```
symbolsC = {"symbols1":('A','B'),"symbols2":('C','D')}
for sym2 in symbolsC["symbols1"]:
    print(str(sym2)+'Z')
for sym1 in symbolsC["symbols2"]:
    print('Z'+str(sym1))
```

but if you need to use that tuples i could not help but i write this:

```
symbols1 = ('A','B')
symbols2 = ('C','D')

symbolsC = {symbols1:('A','B'),symbols2:('C','D')}

for symbol in symbolsC:
    for num in range(len(symbol)):
        print(str(symbol[num])+'Z')
        # print('Z'+str(symbol[num]))
```

maybe you can use an if to make it okay,
really sorry if i could not help

Comment: Thanks. It works. I guess there is no other way than to use 2 for loop statement.

Comment: your welcome, it's my first anwsering i'm so excited

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output does not match the logic you described above. But this will produce

AZ
ZA
BZ
ZB
CZ
ZC
DZ
ZD

```
symbols1 = ('A', 'B')
symbols2 = ('C', 'D')

symbolsC = {symbols1: ('A', 'B'), symbols2: ('C', 'D')}

for symbol in symbolsC.values():
      for value in symbol:
            print(value + 'Z')
            print('Z' + value)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a list if you're just going to get `symbolsC.values()`, also question wanted 4 outputs, not 8